# Matlab functions not 'posting' variables to workspace

Tags: matlab, user-defined-functions

I'm using some user generated functions in MatLab. It'll be quicker if I don't post my actual code here so I'll summarize.

I have two functions. Each of them exist in their own files saved under their proper names. They can be called and work correctly. Lets say function1 is:

```
function [Output1] function1=(a,b)

Output1=a+b

end
```

---

```
function [Output2] function2=(a,Output1)

Output2=a+Output1

end
```

---

*new script file*

```
a=2;
b=3;

function1(a,b);
function2(a,Output1);
```

---

This doesn't work, because function1 isn't posting Output1 into the workspace. How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_functions.htm). This is how you are supposed to write a function.

```
function Output1 = function1(a, b)

Output1 = a + b;

end
```

Then your second function will get the input like this.

```
function Output2 = function2(a, Output1)

Output2 = a + Output1;

end
```

Of course you need to store answers of functions into variables to have them stored in the workspace.

```
aa=2;
bb=3;

Output11 = function1(aa,bb);
Output22 = function2(aa,Output11);
```

If you don't use `Output11` and `Output22`, functions will store their result into `ans` variable in the workspace. And obviously, apart from the fact that you cannot pass the variable to the second function as `Output1`, second function will overwrite the `ans`.

Comment: That's certainly *part* of the problem (although it would have been better to explicitly state that the `=` was in the wrong place), but your answer ignores the fact that the return value of `function1` is not stored in a variable and so cannot be used as an input parameter to `function2`.